# "Post Your Question" and "Post Your Answer" look like Web 1.0 UI buttons

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I like the nice design of the site, it makes me feel good on the inside.  I am sure it's the reason why Apple products can charge $50 for a power cord, because they have nice design.

With that in mind, your "Post Your Question" and "Post Your Answer" seem to be out of date when compared to the rest of the site.  It does not change on hover, or on click.  It also has a very Web 1.0-like look (the padding and padding height on top is less than on bottom).

It just does not look like the rest of the quality material on this site.

The reason why I bring this up is that I feel like attention to detail really makes a site stand out and I feel like you are selling yourself short by leaving such an item undone.

---

To the editors, the "Post Your Question" is no different than the "Answer Your Question".  It just depends on your perspective of the question. Its also the same button as "Save Edits"

---

[image]

So as you can see I included the "Add Comment" button and the "Answer Your Question" (For you it's "Post Your Answer").  There is the spacing issue, measured in gimp.

Comment: Wow, this power cord is amazingly designed.  I shall pay 50$ for it, so that I can plug it into the back of my laptop and hide the rest behind my desk.  Derp.  Also, I don't want my power cords to catch me off guard or make me smile, kthx.

Comment: I'm not seeing the spacing issue you refer to. Can you take a screenshot and annotate it perhaps to show the issue?

Comment: @awoodland its only 1px i believe, but its enough for attention to detailed people to see it.   Just use chrome and do a "Inspect Element" on it and you will see it much more when its nicely color coded.  The height of the element, the line height of the text makes it so that the space below "Answer Your Question" is greater than the space above (by 1 to 2 pxs).

Comment: I think a better argument is that those two buttons are not consistent with the behavior of the other (similar looking) buttons across the top ("Questions", "Tags", "Users" "Ask Question", etc).

Comment: Look directly downwards, it will say "Answer Your Question" at least for me, probably says "Post Your Answer" for you.  Just look at the nav links, perfectly centered, generous padding on right and left, and highlights when hover.  Check out the category items (they act like buttons).  nicely padded all around, text nicely centered.  Now look at the "Post Your Answer" button... It just does not fit with the rest of the design.  Maybe i am just picky... whatever

Comment: Sorry, there are indeed buttons labeled with "Post Your Answer". There's also one labeled "Ask Question", and "Post Your Question".

Comment: @jadarnel27  I just did not say that, but i was thinking it.  Thanks for putting into better words what i was thinking/trying to say.  The button is just inconsistent and looks outdated.

Comment: @slhck I was just trying to clarify (with my edit) that he wasn't referring to the "Ask Question" button (since it already does the hover stuff), but the buttons used for posting a question or answer.  You're good =)

Comment: As far as the spacing issues @awoodland, that has received 5 upvotes, i do not see how its not obvious.  There is a 1-2 px larger bottom.  Its just not centered like the rest of the buttons.  Look at the "Add Comment" button (When adding a comment) and everything is nicely centered.

Comment: @Michael "*i do not see how its not obvious*" - being condescending doesn't help your case.  **Post a screenshot** (zoomed in if it needs to be) **explicitly pointing out the spacing problem**.  Golly.

Comment: Sorry for acting like a child.  I posted the screen shot.

Comment: For me the `Add Comment` button has 6px spacing on top and on bottom. And for `Post your answer` and `Post your question` it's 5px vs 6px. Hardly noticeable, especially since the center of mass of a letter is in the lower part of it. (I use the latest Opera, and measured on meta.SO)

Comment: I also don't see how design is related to web 1.0/2.0, which is an ill defined concept anyways. There have been plenty of well designed sites before the web 2.0 hype, and plenty of badly designed(myspace lol) after.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/

Comment: Well, i should just keep my mouth closed. I guess paying attention to detail is for the birds.  neeto.  Sorry for the suggestion to try to help specific parts to match the rest of the site and not look so crappy.

Comment: @Michael: It's not the paying attention to detail part that is ill-received. It's your attitude (at least initially), the fact that you throw around useless/meaningless/incendiary terms like "Web 1.0", and the incredibly subjective nature of your claim. People are *very* attentive to detail around here, but people disagree about good design. They also disagree about the need for things to be shiny and lickable. Also note that a *constructive* question would do more than just rant—it would propose a concrete alternative, complete with justifications why that would be a positive change.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: The horizontal padding is not quite symmetrical, and the font hinting is slightly off between `Y` and `o`. Clearly, this will not meet the questioner's expectations.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Did you mean kerning? (Although the hinting is a bit off, too.)

Comment: @BoltClock, arr, you're right, that's kerning, not hinting (which is indeed a bit off on the `s` characters). So much for the irony. I'll leave my previous comment there, though, for purely karmic reasons.

Comment: This button doesn't work. Is this a bug? `;)`